# How to make a popup that only pops up once per user?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in web development, and I'm trying to program a website for my class. So I watched a video on making a popup, but the popup comes up every time the user reloads the page. I need help, please.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>KI22 Website</title>

    <!-- FONTAWESOME CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <!--GOOGLE FONTS (MONTSERRAT)-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        <button id="close">&times;</button>
        <h2>Achtung! Wichtige Regeln</h2>
        <p>1.An keine andere Person außerhalb der Klasse teilen!</p>
        <p>2.KEINE SCREENSHOTS!</p>
        <p>3.Nur schulrelevante Dateien hochladen!</p>
    </div>
    <!--==================== END OF POPUP ====================-->

    <nav>
        <div class="container nav__container">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <ul class="nav__menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Hauptmenü</a></li>
                <li><a href="fächer.html">Fächer</a></li>
                <li><a href="mitteilungen.html">Mitteilungen</a></li>
                <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button id="open-menu-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
            <button id="close-menu-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--==================== END OF NAVBAR ====================-->

    <header>
        <div class="container header__container">
            <div class="header__left">
                <h1>Willkommen zur KI Website</h1>
                <p><h4>Diese Website wurde für schulische zwecke von G. Daoud programmiert. Du wirst in der Lage sein, deine Aufzeichnungen von der Unterrichtsstunde auf dieser Website hochzuladen, und die Aufzeichnungen deiner Klassenkameraden zu downloaden.</h4></p>
                <a href="fächer.html" class="btn btn-primary">Loslegen</a>
            </div>

            <div class="header__right">
                <div class="header__right-image">
                    <img src="./images/student.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--==================== END OF HEADER ====================-->





    <section class="discord">
        <div class="container discord__container">
            <div class="discord__left">
                <h1><i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>Discord</h1>
                <p>Hier kannst du Member des Discord-Servers KI22 werden. Wir freuen uns über jeden Member.</p>
                <p>In dem Server hast du die Möglichkeit, uns zu kontaktieren wenn du Probleme mit der Website hast, oder auch wenn es allgemein Probleme im Server gibt.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Member werden</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </section>




    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my JS code:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(
        function open(event) {
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        1000
    )
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
```

I tried to find an answer on google, but those solutions didn't work. I also watched youtube videos, but still nothing.

Comment: It really depends what "one user" means to your app. Maybe storing a cookie saying it's already popped up is adequate. Maybe you need to store some data on your API indicating a user has already seen it so they don't get it on multiple devices. Maybe you just want to use session/local storage. There's a lot of ways to do this, but "once per user" isn't very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) to tell the browser that the page has already been loaded. You'll check if not loaded yet, then open/close your pop up

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
setTimeout(
    function open(event) {
        if(!localStorage.getItem('loaded')){
             document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
             localStorage.setItem('loaded', 'true');
        }
    },
    1000
  )
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
```

when ever you want to open the popup again, call localStorage and reload the page.

```
 localStorage.setItem('loaded',null);
```